# read a .srt file in python and to get the start and end time for each statement in the srt file

Tags: python, project

Read a .srt file and write down the timestamp of each statement and put it in a list. I tried using looking for solutions , but could not find any.

```
import pysrt
subs = pysrt.open(r'C:\Users\nitin\Desktop\example.srt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take items starting after `2h 40min 51sec`, and ending before `0min 51sec` (ending before starting);

This slice is more likely to retrive something

```py
parts = subs.slice(starts_after={'minutes': 0, 'seconds': 51.500}, 
                   ends_before={'minutes': 160, 'seconds': 51.500})
for item in parts:
  print(('%s - %s - %s' % (item.start, item.text, item.end))
```

`start` and `end` are of type `SrtTime` and they have attributes `hours`,
`minutes`, `seconds`, `millisecons`.

And as you see can be converted to string.

Comment: actually i need the code for reading a .srt file and write down the timestamp of each statement and put it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script a while ago to shift the time of srt files. I used regular expressions. here is the code.

```
pattern = r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},d{3}$)|(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if re.match(pattern, text[i]):
            "write code here"
```

Comment: actually i need the code for reading a .srt file and write down the timestamp of each statement and put it in a list.

Comment: You can use this is code for that. Just take the line and append it to a list. If you need time objects you can use strptime()